# How to prove (4|n)→(2|n) in P

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let 4|n means n is divisible by 4. How to prove (4|n)→(2|n) in P?

Knowing that we have ¬(4|5), so we have ¬∀n(4|n). That is, we can not suppose 4|n because otherwise we would have ∀n(4|n) by generalization, but the hypothesis is in contradiction with ¬∀n(4|n). This shows that the hypothetical proof: if B ├ C then ├ B→C of propositional logic cannot be applied to predicate logic.

We prove (4|n)→(2|n) intuitively by suppose 4|n. If we cannot suppose it, how to prove it?

Comment: Please try to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thank you.

Comment: @user49413 I think you have misunderstood. $(4|n) \rightarrow (2|n)$. It is not equivalent to $(4|n) \forall n$. However, it is equivalent $\lnot (4|n) \lor (2|n) \forall n$.

Comment: (4|n)→(2|n) means ∀n((4|n)→(2|n)) by generalization or ∀n(¬(4|n)∨(2|n)) if you prefer. It doesn't mean (∀n(4|n))→(∀n(2|n)).

Comment: If we suppose 4|n, then we would have ∀n(4|n) and would prove (∀n(4|n))→(∀n(2|n)) which is evidently wrong. This is from another point of view why we cannot suppose 4|n.

Answer (score 1):

*Sketch of a proof ([Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/)-like)*.

The proof obviously needs [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic); thus, what we will prove is :

> $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall n \ [\exists k \ (n = 4 \times k) \to \exists l \ (n = 2 \times l)]$.

1. $\exists k \ (n = 4 \times k)$ --- assumed [a] (this is : $4 | n$)
2. $n = 4 \times k_1$ --- assumed [b] from 1) for $\exists$-elim

> 3. $\mathsf {PA} \vdash (4= 2 \times 2)$ --- from [axioms for $\times$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)

4. $n = (2 \times 2) \times k_1$ --- from 2) and 3) by [properties of *equality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_logic_without_equality)

Now we need the *associative law* for $\times$, i.e. :

> $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall a,b,c \ [(a \times b) \times c = a \times (b \times c)]$

and we have, by *transitivity of equality* :

5. $n=2 \times (2 \times k_1)$
6. $\exists l \ (n = 2 \times l)$ --- from 5) by $\exists$-intro (this is : $2 | n$)

> 7. $\exists l \ (n = 2 \times l)$ --- from 1) and 2)-6) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [b]

8. $\exists k \ (n = 4 \times k) \to \exists l \ (n = 2 \times l)$ --- from 1) and 7) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a]

> > 9. $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall n \ [\exists k \ (n = 4 \times k) \to \exists l \ (n = 2 \times l)]$ --- from 8) by [$\forall$-intro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

---

*Note* : you concern about Deduction Theorem is right for Hilbert-styple proof systems with "unrestricted" Generalization rule (see Mendelson's textbook).

The restriction on Universal generalization rule typical of Natural Deduction gives us the benefit of using $\to$-introduction rule (aka : Deduction Theorem) without restrictions also in predicate calculus.

In any case, the above proof is sound also for Mendelson's system, because the only use of Generalization in performed after the Deduction Th step to a variable $n$ that is not free in any assumption.

Comment: By 1), you suppose 4|n. But you introduce contradiction already by this step!

Comment: @user49413 Your question seems to be asking how to use $4\mid n$ to show that $2\mid n$ for some $n$. Why would supposing $4\mid n$ introduce contradiction?

Comment: It's in the question itself. If we suppose 4|n, then we have ∀n(4|n) by generalization. But we have already ¬∀n(4|n) by ¬(4|5). So to suppose 4|n leads to contradiction.

Comment: @user49413 - [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) does **not** work that way. I've assumed $∃k (n=4×k)$ and derived $∃l (n=2×l)$, then use Deduction Theorem to get $∃k (n=4×k) \to ∃l (n=2×l)$ and finally Gen to get : $\forall n [∃k (n=4×k) \to ∃l (n=2×l)]$.

Comment: The step "1) ∃k (n=4×k) --- 4|n" means "if 4|n, then ∃k (n=4×k)". Otherwise, what is the reason for "∃k (n=4×k)"? So, you suppose 4|n.

Comment: Or in other word, ∃k (n=4×k) is the definition of 4|n. So, you suppose ∃k (n=4×k) or 4|n is the same.

Comment: You "assume ∃k(n=4×k)" then you assume also contradiction. You then "deduct ∃l(n=2×l)". Who know that your result is not deducted from contradiction, that is, could be FALSE? This question refutes in reality the deduction theorem in predicate logic. The theorem holds only in propositional logic. I means here by how the theorem is proven. What I doubt is not the result of the theorem in predicate logic, but is for what reason it holds for predicate logic.

Comment: The modification of Mendelson to the first order logic by introducing the notion of dependence in a deduction is too complicated. And it's not intuitive. I think that to use restricted domain of discourse and the conversion of formula between different domains of discourse is more mechanical and intuitive.

Comment: Dependency check is inconvenient because we should pay attention to each step of deduction, and the check becomes more and more complicated when the number of steps becomes bigger.

Comment: It's difficult to accept the Mendelson's version of deduction theorem for predicate logic because it infringes the law of no contradiction. It's equivalent to say that contradiction is not a problem if we pay attention to avoid generation of FALSE result from it. This kind of method is acceptable in a dialectic system but not in a deduction system.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume what you want to prove is $(\forall n\in \mathbb{Z})[4|n\implies 2|n]$ (I'm not sure what your $P$ stands for, positive integers?)

Proof: For any integer $n$, if $4|n$, we can find an integer $p$ such that $4p=n$ (This follows by the Division Theorem). Then, by arithmetic we have $4p=2(2p)=n$. Since $p$ is an integer, $2p$ is also an integer. Thus, let $q=2p$, and we have found the integer $q$ that satisfies $2q=n$. By the definition of divisibility, $2|n$. That completes the proof.

Clarification: To prove the implication, we do not suppose $4|n$ for all $n$, we suppose that for each possible $n$.

Comment: In your proof, you say "if 4|n", so you suppose 4|n. I know that what you mean for "if 4|n" is not ∀n(4|n) but "for the n so that 4|n". But in P, that is, in your n∈Z, to suppose 4|n does mean ∀n(4|n). That is THE PROBLEM. So, my question is in reality could we prove the formula without supposing 4|n?

Comment: @user49413 I see what you mean now. Of course, prove the contrapositive, so you assume not (2|n) and prove not (4|n)

Comment: We meet the same problem: we cannot assume 2|n because we have ¬(2|3) so ¬∀n(2|n).

Comment: @user49413 I think your logic is not quite right. We test for each n, what will happen if we assume 2|n, not 2|n for all n.

Comment: I know that by supposing 2|n, what we would like to mean is "for the n so that 2|n", but not "∀n(2|n)". But at the actual status, in theory, to assume 2|n means to add 2|n, temporally, to the theory system so we can use it as a TRUE formula, so means ∀n(2|n).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that (4|n)→(2|n) can be proven in P. I think that it could be necessary to add a new rule of deduction for that. Let's call it the rule of conditional deduction and denote it by CDt here.

With CDt, we deduct in a restricted domain of discourse. The domain of discourse of P is natural number N. For any non empty class C⊂N, CDt works as a theory system P' that is the same as P except that its domain of discourse is C. Then, all TRUE formulas in P free of the quantifier ∃ are TRUE formula in P'. A TRUE formula in P containing ∃ cannot be translated to P'. Knowing that ¬∀x(f(x)) should be considered as ∃x(¬f(x)), and ¬∃x(f(x)) should be considered as ∀x(¬f(x)). So, we have less TRUE formulas in P' than in P at beginning of CDt. A TRUE formula in P' containing neither free variable nor quantifier ∀ is also a TRUE formula in P. A TRUE formula containing free variable x denoted by f(x) can be translated to a TRUE formula in P by (x∈C)→f(x), similarly, ∀x(f(x)) to ∀x((x∈C)→f(x)).

With CDt for proving (4|n)→(2|n), we use the C relative to the formula 4|n according to the axiom IV.1 which is similar to the axiom of comprehension. So, we have ∀n((n∈C)↔(4|n)) in P so also in P'.

We can add 4|n to P', or in other words assume 4|n in P', under CDt because the ¬(4|5) in P cannot lead to contradiction in P' for the reason that 5 is not in C. Then we can obtain 2|n by deduction in P', and translate 2|n in P' to (4|n)→(2|n) in P.

This process is the same as what we do usually by intuition. So, CDt just formalize what we do usually by introducing restricted domain of discourse. We get (4|n)→(2|n) by extension of domain of discourse, but not by reason that it's part of some TRUE formula or it's defined recursively.

In general, the restricted domain of discourse can be extended to variable domain of discourse that can further be used to extend P to a bigger domain of discourse. For example, (4|n)→(2|n) would become isN(n)→((4|n)→(2|n)) where isN(x) is TRUE if and only if x is a natural number. This would permit a unified formal theory system by mixing all theory systems in a unified domain of discourse: the universe.